# How many Pseudo-classes are there in CSS?

Tags: css

How many Pseudo-classes are there in CSS? What are they?

Comment: Which version of CSS? 2.1 or 3 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A bunch of useful one](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors)s.

I mostly use: :hover :active but :before :after and :first-child are useful too.

Answer (score 3):

See [5.10 Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-elements) of the CSS2 spec.

[CSS3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work#selectors) are in Last Call status.  See [6.6 Pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-selectors-20090310/#pseudo-classes), and [7 Pseudo elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-selectors-20090310/#pseudo-elements).